# Facebook login through Facebook messenger webview doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, facebook, webview

I have a web app that uses Facebook login, everything works fine on web browsers on phones.
When users access my app through links in Facebook messenger, the facebook login doesn't respond and I am not able to see the error code or logs, since I don't have access to the webview itself.

I get `Submit for Login Review, Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook`.

Any ideas on how I can continue from here?